# What is limit of Nested IF statement in MS Word?

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

Is there any limit on how many nesting we can use in Nested IF statement in Microsoft Word?

Also, if limit can be different based on office version?

Comment: This is not a programming question and is therefore off-topic on Stack Overflow. End-user questions belong on a site such as Super User. But why don't you try it, yourself? Or search (Google) for the keywords `Microsoft Word limitations` and see what you turn up. FWIW in this respect all versions a likely the same since the fields technology hasn't been changed in decades...

Comment: On the contrary, as has been established in numerous threads here, field coding is programming.

Comment: @CindyMeister - I had already tried to search on Google but I was unable to find any official documentation that talks about IF statement. And, this is not a End User perspective question. I believe Writing IF statement is a 'Programming' part. So, I thought to ask question over here.

Answer (score 1):

The nesting limit is 20 in all Word versions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As such I have tried to find Microsoft official documentation for this limitation but I was unable to find. Do you know any link that says about this limitation.

Comment: The current doco is at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/operating-parameter-limitation. However, that omits much that was previously documented. See, for example: http://web.archive.org/web/20090506160536/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211489

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but this may help others. You only need ONE else statement at the end. There is no need to nest. Example:

```
{IF { MERGEFIELD LETTERCODE } = "A" "LETTER A TEXT HERE" 
}{IF { MERGEFIELD LETTERCODE } = "B" "LETTER B TEXT HERE" 
}{IF { MERGEFIELD LETTERCODE } = "C" "LETTER C TEXT HERE" 
}{IF { MERGEFIELD LETTERCODE } = "D" "LETTER D TEXT HERE" 
"ELSE DEFAULT LETTER TEXT HERE" }
```

I've done 80+ versions like this.